# How to display different HTML elements in if statement

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, ejs

**Hello, I am new to HTML and JS therefore would like to ask for some help.
Here I want to display two different HTML elements according if statement is true or false. However, it does not work.
Could I get some help? (:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<script>
if (!user) {
    <h1> there is no user </h1>
} </script>


if (user) {
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
} </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `document.write()`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a native Javascript alternative

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>

<script>

    var el = document.getElementById('content');
    var content;

    if  (!user) {
        content = '<h1>there is no user</h1>';
    }
    if  (user) {
        content = '<button type="button">Click Me!</button>';
    }

    el.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', content);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This won't work as is unless the `user` variable is defined, though, but I'm assuming you already have it available at runtime.

If you have more html in this div you can use a different insert position, see the documentation about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Answer (score 2):

Using `jQuery` you would do something like this

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
if(!user){
   $('body').append('<h1>There is no user</h1>')
} else if(user) {
   $('body').append('<button>Login</button>')
}
```

[See js fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/cfftus67/).

Also, note that if you want to use jquery include the script in the head

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you are using jquery here and calling as javascript. what is this. He is new to `HTML` and `JS`.

Comment: OP is new to JS. I doubt they know how to import and use jQuery.

Comment: yes this is a way. But if are trying to learn core `PHP` and I give solution of your problem in `Laravel`. What you understand depend upon you.ya.

Comment: Just solving problem is not great.How much question owner get satisfaction is most important.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't add HTML directly in a block of javascript. What you can do instead though is use jQuery to append a block of HTML.

To do this, you would load jQuery by adding this line to your head tag

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

And then replace your inline javascript with the following:

```
<script>
if (!user) {
  $(document.body).append( "<h1> there is no user </h1>" );
}


if (user) {
  $(document.body).append( "<button type='button'>Click Me!</button>" );
} </script>
```

Comment: @Edga  if you are new to JS then try to learn JS first.Then see `Jquery`. will be grear.